# Not updating value in database instead Inserting new entry

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using below code to update database and putting where clause for date

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DBTransactions.USER_ID_KEY, userId);
    values.put(DBTransactions.DATE_KEY, date);
    values.put(DBTransactions.DAY_KEY, day);
    values.put(DBTransactions.GOAL_KEY, dailyGoal);
    values.put(DBTransactions.VOLUME_KEY, dailyVolume);
    values.put(DBTransactions.IS_GOAL_MET_KEY, goalMet);
    db.getWritableDatabase().update(DBTransactions.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME, values, DBTransactions.DATE_KEY + " = ?", new String[]{date});
    closeDB();
```

am I wrong somewhere in putting where clause? Its not updating database, Its creating new entry in database.

Its not updating database.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should show some logs or exceptions...

Comment: There is no exception I am getting, Its inserting new entry instead of updating the same value

Comment: Can you please post of creating table and also the column data types?

Comment: its Happened, because of not finding that date who's passing in where clause...its a Default behavior of update Query. plz verify it, which type of date you are storing and passing in where clause both should be in same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am using  this code for update me Database and it's work fine , not a issue with me .

```
  public void updateItemToCartTable(String itemId, String subitemid, String cost, int quantity) {

    sdb = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(ITEM_COST, cost);
    values.put(ITEM_QUANTITY, quantity);

    Log.d("DB", "Count : " + quantity);

    this.sdb.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ITEM_ID + " ='" + itemId + "'         AND " + SUB_ITEM_ID + " ='" + subitemid + "'", null);
    sdb.close();
}
```

Use This Code For Updating your Database

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code to update your table:**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DBTransactions.USER_ID_KEY, userId);
values.put(DBTransactions.DATE_KEY, date);
values.put(DBTransactions.DAY_KEY, day);
values.put(DBTransactions.GOAL_KEY, dailyGoal);
values.put(DBTransactions.VOLUME_KEY, dailyVolume);
values.put(DBTransactions.IS_GOAL_MET_KEY, goalMet);

db.update(DBTransactions.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME, values, DBTransactions.DATE_KEY + " = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(date)});

closeDB();
```

Answer (score 0):

- What is data type of DBTransactions.DATE_KEY column in DBTransactions.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME table?
- Insert data in local database and check the format in which date is inserting in DBTransactions.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME table.
- While updating record based on DBTransactions.DATE_KEY condition, check DBTransactions.DATE_KEY matches value stored in DBTransactions.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME DBTransactions.DATE_KEY column.

Everything else in your code seems to be fine.